# Native graphics in Android NDK : OpenGLES vs Native WIndow API

Tags: android, c++, graphics, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am confused about which approach to follow to design the UI for my Android native app, which I will completely in C++ and I dont want to use JNI and Java for the developing the UI.

Can anyone shed some light on which approach is better for Native graphics in Android NDK
`OpenGLES` or `Native Window API` and why ? I am referring a book in which i have found the following options:

[image: Available options]

**Definition for Native WIndow API :**  Starting from Android API level 9, the Android NDK provides an API to enable the native code to
directly access and manipulate the pixel buffer of the native window. This API is known as the native
windows API.

Comment: Do you want to handle rendering yourself (e.g. directly touching all of the pixels in a framebuffer), or draw everything with OpenGL ES?  What does your app *do*?

Comment: Are you looking for simple 2D line, curve, and shape drawing?

Comment: yes i am looking for 2D drawing